# Rounded corner box technique with images all around as borders

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know good example of using CSS to create rounded corner box where:

1. All 4 corners and 4 sides are image. The sides have repeated `img`
2. The width is constant while height is flexible
3. Work all in FF 3.x, IE 7 or higher, Chrome

Let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do it with 3 divs.

```
<div class="bg"><div class="top"><div class="bot">text here</div></div></div>
```

`bg` would have css like

```
background: url(path/to/repeated/background.gif) repeat-y;
```

Where the background spans the entire width of the div, since it's constant. That will tile both your left and right sides.

And then for the top and bottom just use images with `no-repeat top left;` and `no-repeat bottom left`. They would each have 2 corners plus all the imagey goodness inbetween.

Hopefully you can fill in the details from that if you have a good enough understanding of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't know any such codes. But i know a best code for css rounded corners without images.

Check out this [link](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/08/css3-rounded-corners-for-every-browser.html)

Its work in all browsers and easy to implement. The great thing is it works well in ie6!..Great na..

Comment: Might as well link directly to curvycorners rather than a blog post about curvycorners

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 properties for border images are as follows:

```
border-image:
border-top-image
border-right-image
border-bottom-image
border-left-image
border-corner-image:
border-top-left-image
border-top-right-image
border-bottom-left-image
border-bottom-right-image
```

Example:

```
border-image: url(border.png) 27 27 27 27 round round;
```

Mozilla differs from IE,Chrome,Safari i.e
using properties starting with **-moz** other than **-webkit**

For more explanation about these properties please look at these definitions and examples.

[Source1](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/),
  [Source2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-background-20050216/#the-border-radius)